# Build separate pages or not

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have about 20 grid views that I have to create. All of them are pretty standard across the board. Just take IEnumerable T and display it in a grid view, that's it.

I would prefer to create one aspx page and have the grid view be dynamically generated by using ITemplate. And I guess for the data source use IEnumerable Object.

Are there significant performance considerations between doing it the way I'd like to do it or would it be better to go ahead and build the 20 or more grid views on separate aspx pages?

An example of a concern I have is taking List T and casting to IEnumerable T where T is type Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having one generic view page is preferable - where it is possible which it sounds like it is in your case.

Secondly no performance hit going from List to IEnumerable as IEnumerable is a behaviour which List has.

However you will get a performance hit building a List if you don't already have it - it is much better to ensure that you are passing IEnumerable from the LINQ statements directly as it is only realized when used - which can have major benefit with long lists and when using sorting or filtering (because you can modify the IEnumerable before it is realized)

As with anything related to performance build it and profile it to see if performance is an issue. No amount of opinion, however well informed is a substitute for profiling and only optimising when necessary, always avoid premature optimisation.

Answer (score 2):

Build just the one and performance test. It will be easier to apply lessons learned.

If the data is long, turn buffering off to improve time to first byte.

Comment: Can you help me understand what you mean when you say, "turn buffering off..."

Comment: <%@ Page ... Buffer="False" %> by default this is True, meaning the entire page, down to the last byte, sits in memory until it's completely written out. Then it's sent to the client. If the page is long, you're wasting the user's time. If the page is short, turning this off can waste server and client CPU.

Answer (score 1):

20 grid views, Ok

Just make sure you **disable the ViewState** of the controls that do not require it.

That will considerably reduce you page size & in turn reduce the page load time.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing custom and you have to only show default data for all 20 tables/lists then i think you should use one page